# Do Specific Job For Specific System By Batch "CMD" File

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command

I need your help, I'm building small installation batch file for my small application (My app.exe must be copied in different places of windows version and architecture).

I played with it, but can't solve the given task...

I created this code: (For testing purposes)

```
If Exist "C:\Users\All Users\ntuser.dat" Goto Win 7
If Exist "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\ntuser.dat" Goto Win XP

:Win 7

C:\w7\test.txt

:Win XP

C:\wxp\test.txt
```

But when executing the batch file (from windows xp) both jobs are done (Both files are opened)... why I can't understand... as I know it must open only win xp section code

Please how to modify the code, give me an example..

My Mission is:

I want that my app.exe file copied in different locations of different windows versions and builds (WinXP - X86-X64, Win7 - X86-X64)

If it is windows 7x64 x86 or win xp-x86,x64 it must only use the code which is set for the given system and not other

Thank You In Advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell it to stop running when it reaches the end of that section, or it will keep going into the next one. (Spaces in the branch labels aren't really a good idea either, although they're allowed. Why use them, when the user will never see them?)

```
If Exist "C:\Users\All Users\ntuser.dat" Goto Win7
If Exist "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\ntuser.dat" Goto WinXP

:Win7
C:\w7\test.txt
goto :eof

:WinXP
C:\wxp\test.txt
goto :eof
```

`:eof` is a pre-defined branch label that means `end of file`. More info in the [`goto` documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755012.aspx)

Comment: Ken One More question about this and it will be solved: how to add to this x86 and x64 bits and also windows 8 32-64 bits..... greatest thanks in advanced

Comment: @Vako, that's a totally separate question than the one you asked here. If you want to ask about that subject, post a new question. The rule here is "One question per post", and you can't start a new one in the comments. :-) (The location of `ntuser.dat` is a bad way to decide where you should put files, BTW. There are free installation software builders that can do this properly for you. One suggestion is [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org).)

Comment: Ok Ken (Sorry I'm new here and not accustomed the rules well yet)  :)

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
If Exist "C:\Users\All Users\ntuser.dat" Goto Win_7
If Exist "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\ntuser.dat" Goto Win_XP

:Win_7

C:\w7\test.txt
goto:eof

:Win_XP

C:\wxp\test.txt
goto:eof
```